# Qt creator add celsius sign end of label

Tags: qt, label, sign

I am using a label for showing temperature value, and i want to add celcius sign to this label like this: "27°C". I am using this code:

```
ui->label->setText(tempvalue)
```

but how can i add "°C" at the end of this? Like this ;

```
ui->label->setText(tempvalue°C)
```

Comment: ui->label->setText(tempValue + "°C" );  // might work.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QString::fromUtf8` for this:

```
ui->label->setText(tempvalue + QString::fromUtf8("°C"));
```

This matters if your source file not UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Another option worked for me:

```
ui->label->setText(tempvalue + QChar(0x2103));
```

Comment: Is this *significantly* different from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77612919/10871073)?

Comment: For me all other options did not work so i thought it might be helpful as well;)